# Can we send data with redirect in node

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send data with redirect as:

```
this.redirect("/home",{message:'hello'});
```

but I got the result like:

```
undefined redirect to home
```

If anyone faced this problem, please help.

**Using framework**: `locomotive`

Comment: What framework do you use?

Comment: If you're using Express, you can use the middleware [express-flash](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-flash).

Comment: @AlexeyTen i m using locomotive framework

Comment: @user3680001 that should be mentioned in question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [express-flash](https://github.com/RGBboy/express-flash):

```
app.use(flash());
...

app.get('/redirect', function (req, res) {
  req.flash('info', 'Flash Message Added');
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

You data are acessile in `res.locals.messages` so in your views just in `messages` var.

express flash is based on connect flash. It uses sessions to transmit messages.

If you are using locomotive

> Locomotive builds on Express, preserving the power and simplicity you've come to expect from Node.

so:

```
module.exports = function() {

  ...
  this.use(express.bodyParser());
  this.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  this.use(flash());
  ...
}
```

Comment: this answer is not good enough, how do we attach the data in the primary redirect? as in the original question - .redirect("/home",{message:'hello'}); he is trying attach the data "message". how do we send that data to the app.get(/redirect,function{}); method???

Answer (score 0):

You can, but do not need to, use the express-flash module for flash messaging. The req.session and res.locals objects exposed by the express-session module provide an avenue for writing your own flash middleware to more precisely meet your needs. This one is adapted from Ethan Brown's book, Web Development with Node & Express.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  // if there's a flash message in the session request, make it available in the response
  res.locals.flash = req.session.flash;
  // then delete it
  delete req.session.flash;
  next();
});
```

Set the flash message using req.session.flash before redirecting to the target route.

```
req.session.sessionFlash = {
  type: 'success',
  message: 'This is a flash message using custom middleware and express-session.'
}
```

Retrieve the flash message using res.locals.flash in the target route's res.render method.

```
res.render('index', { flash: res.locals.flash });
```

See my Gist below for more details about flash messaging in Express 4.

https://gist.github.com/brianmacarthur/a4e3e0093d368aa8e423